# How to git pull before npm start with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to pull my files from git before running my app, I'm using `git pull && node ./bin/www` and the application hangs.I'm new to `Nodejs` Is there another way of doing this?

```
{
  "name": "matcha",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "git pull && node ./bin/www"
},
  "dependencies": {
  "base-64": "^0.1.0",
  "bcryptjs": "^2.3.0",
  "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
  "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
  "crypto": "0.0.3",
  "debug": "~2.2.0",
  "ejs": "~2.5.2",
  "express": "~4.14.0",
  "express-session": "^1.14.2",
  "fs": "0.0.1-security",
  "morgan": "~1.7.0",
  "multer": "^1.2.0",
  "mysql": "^2.12.0",
  "nodemailer": "^2.6.4",
  "path": "^0.12.7",
  "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
},
  "repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://github.com/julekgwa/Matcha.git"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the application hangs?

Comment: The git command finishes but `node ./bin/www` doesn't start.

Comment: It does not start silently? Should not there be an error message? Actually I would also add npm install after git pull

Comment: Theres no error message, just hangs.

Comment: Are you sure it hangs? it looks like just a web server which does not stop because it should not

Comment: Yes thank you, the web server is running, I thought it hangs as it should display a message showing that the server is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `prestart`.

When you are updating your dependencies, you need run `npm install`. So scripts example is:

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "git pull && npm install",
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @galkin answer, but with checking if the package.json or package-lock.json changed before running npm install. Also, only install dependencies from package-lock.json, and only production dependencies.

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "if git pull | grep 'package'; then npm ci --production; fi",
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  },
```